# Polymer paper-dropdown's core-select event fired by another element's core-selector

Tags: polymer, paper-elements, core-elements

I have run into a problem where paper-dropdown element's on-core-select event is being fired by a core-selector belonging to a separate element in my polymer app.  Here are excerpts from the polymer element that includes the paper-dropdown (along with the polymer event script):

```
<paper-dropdown id="widthUnits" class="unitSelection" selected="{{item.data.designWidth[1]}}" on-core-select="{{ conditionUnitSelectionChanged }}" valueattr="label">
                        <paper-item label="mm"></paper-item>
                        <paper-item label="cm"></paper-item>
                        <paper-item label="m"></paper-item>
</paper-dropdown>


conditionUnitSelectionChanged: function(e, detail, sender) {
      // Ensure the selection has in fact changed
      if (sender.selected != detail.item.label)
      {                    
          this.ajaxUpdateUnit(sender);
      }
},
```

And here is the core-selector and related code that is part of an entirely different element within the application. FYI, `SelectedItemKey` is watched by polymer 'Changed' events in both of the elements involved...if that matters.

```
<core-selector id="itemSelector" target="{{$.itemList}}" multi="false" selected="{{selectedItemKey}}" selectedAttribute="active"></core-selector>

<div id="itemList" layout horizontal wrap>

        <template repeat="{{item, i in items}}">

            <div id="{{item.name}}">
                <entriesHeading name="{{item.name}}" horizontal layout center>
                    <div flex>{{item.name}}</div>
                    <paper-menu-button icon="more-vert" halign="right">
                        <paper-item label="Edit" on-tap="{{ itemEdit }}"></paper-item>
                        <paper-item label="Copy" on-tap="{{ itemCopy }}"></paper-item>
                        <paper-item label="Delete" on-tap="{{ itemDelete }}"></paper-item>
                    </paper-menu-button>
                </entriesHeading>
                <entriesContainer vertical layout>
                    *** container contents ***
                </entriesContainer>
            </div>

        </template>

</div>
```

Any suggestions on how I can avoid this unwanted interplay with core-select events?  Perhaps a specific listener of some sort (limited to listening for paper-dropdown(s) core-select event)?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the overall structure of your app. Is it possible the `core-select` event is bubbling up and being picked up by the `on-core-select` handler on your paper-dropdown? If that's the you could call `stopPropagation()` when the event fires on #itemSelector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible for the `paper-dropdown` to receive an event from anywhere but inside it's own subtree. You have to present a jsbin or some kind of reproduction, otherwise I must suggest your diagnosis is incorrect.

You should try to figure out what is going on with the events, to make sure you have good understanding of the system.

Having said that, another way of approaching the problem is by being data-driven and not control-driven.

IOW, it's best to react to data-changes instead of events. It's hard to give really good suggestions because I can only see a tiny piece of your application, but here are some suggestions:

You have

```
<paper-dropdown id="widthUnits" class="unitSelection" 
   selected="{{item.data.designWidth[1]}}" 
   on-core-select="{{ conditionUnitSelectionChanged }}" valueattr="label">
```

It's a bit unfortunate that this important data is referenced as `item.data.designWidth[1]`. Generally one wants to factor the application data so that you aren't using deeply nested expressions like that. Just as an example, if you could build a UI like `design-width-editor` and bind it to `<design-width-editor designWidth="{{item.data.designWidth[1]}}">` then you could put logic inside of `design-width-editor` that just deals with `designWidth` and doesn't need to know about `item` or `data`. This gives you a lot more flexibility with your data structures and makes it easier to think  about.

In any case, given the construction you have, one thing you could do is observe the data directly:

```
observe: {
  'item.data.designWidth[1]`: 'designWidth1Changed'
}
```

Now you can implement `designWidth1Changed()` to take the needed action. The key bit here is that you are no longer dependent on any particular UI for modifying the designWidth data. You can replace that UI at will; all that matters is that if the value changes, some action is taken.

Comment: If there are multiple instances of paper-dropdowns within the same element (I am only showing one in the above example), and the selected attribute's for each paper-dropdown are bound to array elements as shown in this single example (i.e. `{{item.data.designWidth[1]}}` for the first dropdown and different item.data properties for the others in the element).  How would one specify the selectedChanged event?  I tried implementing a `selectedChanged` polymer function and also tried `itemChanged`as well, neither of which fired when dropdown selection changed.

Comment: Sorry, I went too fast and gave you some wrong information. There is no `selectedChanged` in your setup to listen to. I'm going to update my answer to make more sense.

Comment: I have taken your advice and refactored the code, building a custom `item-valueeditor` element...a generic compound element consisting of a paper-input (for value input), and paper-dropdown (for unit selection)).  For example, `item-valueeditor` publishes attribute `inputvalue` which is bound to `item.data.designWidth[0]`, and attribute `inputunitvalue` which is bound to `item.data.designWidth[1]`.  Those specific `item.data` values are then individually observed by the host element.  The problem now is that the various observation functions fire when the selected `item` itself changes.

Comment: Continued...  Is there a best-practice pattern or approach to prevent or bypass observed functions when, for instance, I am first loading the `item` or the user has selected a different `item` from a collection?

Comment: See code below...used async to my advantage in order to avoid problem of observe functions running when I don't want them to.

Answer (score 1):

Scott put me on the right track.  After some refactoring as described in the previous comments, I used `async` to my advantage in order to avoid observers executing when I didn't want them to (such as when the elements model `item` object changed...and therefore all of its observed properties).  Here is a sample of some of the script code from the host element mentioned above that was implemented to resolve the final issue:

```
ignoreChanges: null,

observe: {
   'item.data.designWidth[0]': 'designWidthValueChanged',
   'item.data.designWidth[1]': 'designWidthUnitChanged',
}

designWidthValueChanged: function(oldVal, newVal) {
    if (!this.ignoreChanges) {
        // send update of width value input via ajax
        this.ajaxUpdateCondition("designWidth", newVal, this.item.data.designWidth[1]);
    }
},

designWidthUnitChanged: function(oldVal, newVal) {
    if (!this.ignoreChanges) {
        // send update of width unit selection via ajax
        this.ajaxUpdateCondition("designWidth", this.item.data.designWidth[0], newVal);
    }
},

itemKeyChanged: function(oldVal, newVal) {
    // itemKey is a published attribute that is 2 way bound to a parent element (where item selection occurs from a collection)                
    this.toggleIgnoreChanges(true); //set flag to ignore changes to observed values while item object switches 
    this.item = this.items[newVal]; //point to the correct/selected item in the collection (items is published attribute of this element)
    this.async(this.toggleIgnoreChanges);  //reset flag after observe functions have executed
},

toggleIgnoreChanges: function(flagstatus) {
    this.ignoreChanges = flagstatus || !this.ignoreChanges;
}
```